# How to pass data from service to controller AngularJS + Stripe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, angular-services

I am implementing the Stripe payment method in ionic app and need to get the `token` from the service.

Problem I am facing is that, `console.log(token)` in `StripeService` is consoling the token but I need to pass this to my controller to do some extra stuff.

I tried `return token;` in `this.open()` method and `console.log(StripeService.open(amount))` but no luck.

I am trying this - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Let me know how could I get the token from service to my controller.

**Code -**

Following is my AngularJS service code -

```
.service('StripeService', function(){

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_6776Randomkey8990',
    image: '/img/logo.png',
    locale: 'auto'
    });

    this.open = function(amount) {
        return handler.open({
            name: 'mywebsite.com',
            description: 'Pay via stripe',
            amount: amount,
            token: function(token) {
                console.log(token);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Following is my method in controller and calling the service -

```
  $scope.clicked = function(amount) {
      StripeService.open(amount);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`promises`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to return the token.

Service:

```
.service('StripeService', ['$q', function($q){

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_6776Randomkey8990',
        image: '/img/logo.png',
        locale: 'auto'
    });

    this.open = function(amount) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        handler.open({
            name: 'mywebsite.com',
            description: 'Pay via stripe',
            amount: amount,
            token: function(token) {
                deferred.resolve(token);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.clicked = function(amount) {
      StripeService.open(amount).then(function(token){
          console.log('token', token);
      });
  };
```

I didn't tested, but should works!

Comment: How could I get this to work on mobile? on mobile stripe checkout opens a new tab and only true onclick events open a new tab, so handler.open from an ng-click isn't opening the form

Answer (score 1):

As manzapanza says you can use promise, personally I prefer this new notation:

Service:

```
.service('StripeService', ['$q', function($q){

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_6776Randomkey8990',
    image: '/img/logo.png',
    locale: 'auto'
    });

    this.open = function(amount) {
        return $q(function(resolve) {
            handler.open({
                name: 'mywebsite.com',
                description: 'Pay via stripe',
                amount: amount,
                token: function(token) {
                    console.log(token);
                    resolve(token);
                }
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
$scope.clicked = function(amount) {
    StripeService.open(amount).then(function(token){
        console.log('token', token);
    });
};
```